Unpacking Tuples into two tuples
Can a tuple be unpacked to two tuples?
E.g.: countries=("China","Japan","India","England","France") –
unpack this tuple to two tuples, first tuple consisting of first three countries and second tuple consisting of last two countries.
I am able to unpack it into a string and tuple, but cannot find a way to unpack it in two tuples/lists.

I guess this is a special case of this question and can be handled similarly. Since you have a tuple of fixed length and know the lengths of the results, you can unroll the loops suggested in the  answers of the linked question.

countries = ("China", "Japan", "India", "England", "France")

# Unpack the tuple into two tuples
first_tuple = countries[:3]
second_tuple = countries[3:]

print("First Tuple:", first_tuple)
print("Second Tuple:", second_tuple)


You could also use print(f"{first_tuple=}") for printing, which prints first_tuple=('China', 'Japan', 'India'), thus conveys the same information but makes you write less code.

@simon nice tip

You can slice a tuple in the same way that you might slice a list.
Therefore:
countries = ("China", "Japan", "India", "England", "France")

t1, t2 = countries[:3], countries[3:]
print(t1, t2)

Output:
('China', 'Japan', 'India') ('England', 'France')


@Cincinnatus I missed that requirement. Although the main point of the solution is that tuples can be sliced

@Cincinnatus Please re-read the question. It is very specific about the size of the tuples

As a general case, you have basically 2 cases to consider: When your input is even and when your input is odd.
Even inputs are trivial, but odd inputs have 2 ways of splitting: Either the first tuple has one more element or the second tuple is the one having one more element.
To match your requirement, this answer splits odd inputs in such way that the first tuple will take one more element. If you want the other way around, just remove the + 0.5 from the code.
countries=("China","Japan","India","England","France")
first, second = [countries[:int(len(countries)/2 + 0.5)],
                 countries[int(len(countries)/2 + 0.5):]]

print(first)
('China', 'Japan', 'India')

print(second)
('England', 'France')

Inputs with even number of elements:
countries=("China","Japan","India","England")

("China","Japan")  , ("India","England")

Edge cases: Input with 1 element
countries=("China",)

("China",)  , ()

Edge cases: Input with 0 elements
countries=()

()  , ()

